# Move figcaption inside anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to modify the DOM to move the figcaption inside the a element. I'm trying something like this, but not working:

```js
$('.wp-caption-text.gallery-caption').insertAfter('img.attachment-full');
```

This is my code:

```html
<figure class="gallery-item">
  <div class="gallery-icon landscape">
    <a href="#" class="fancybox image" rel="gallery-0"><img src="#" class="attachment-full"></a>
  </div>
  <figcaption class="wp-caption-text gallery-caption" id="gallery-1-365">
    <h2>GILLES HERZOG</h2>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Any ideas?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: It works fine on Chrome/Mac! => [http://cl.ly/image/1S2S1A1q3X28](http://cl.ly/image/1S2S1A1q3X28)